# Docker nginx with ubuntu not working on a custom port

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I have set the following in my ubuntu nginx configuration with docker and this is the nginx configuration

```
server {
listen 6090;
server_name mydomain.com;
location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
       proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:6090;

 }

}
```

The above fails to work but works when i change the listening port to 80 that is by changing `listen 6090` to `listen 80` it works. Am accessing this by visiting the url `mydomain.com:6090`

But i would like to visit my url as `mydomain.com:6090` what else do i need to make this work

In the above mydomain.com is not the actual url.

UPDATES this is my docker configuration for nginx

```
webserver:
 image: nginx
 container_name: webserver
 restart: unless-stopped
 tty: true
 ports:
 - "80:80"
 - "443:443"
```

Comment: what does the error log say ? check `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or `nginx -t` if you mean nginx fail to start at all otherwise let us know the exact issue that you are getting or explain what do you mean by `fails`

Comment: nginx is never reached on the application. It displays This site can’t be reached.

Comment: well, it's trying to do a proxy_pass on itself...

Answer (score 1):

you need to listen and expose the same `Ports`  to make it works:

nginx config:

```
listen 6090;
```

compose:

```
 ports:
   - "6090:6090"
```

you `expose` port `80` therefore `listen 80` will work ...